# AS3 MVC Can You Have Multiple Different Change Events in a Model Class?

Tags: flash, model-view-controller, flash-builder, actionscript-3

Currently I am writing a flash actionscript 3 game, and I use dispatch events from the model class to tell the view classes to update themselves. The problem though is that I have two variables whose dispatch events are for completely different reasons, and I would like to not have both listeners get triggered each time one of the model variables gets set.

currently, a variable's getter/setter in the model class looks like this:

```
public function get swankle():Boolean
        {
            return _swankle;
        }

        public function set swankle(value:Boolean):void
        {
            _swankle = value;
            dispatchEvent(new Event(Event.CHANGE));
        }
```

Possible solutions I have come up with:

- Name your CHANGE events somehow
- Create a new model class each time you need a new CHANGE event

Let me know what you guys think is the best way.

Cheers,
Jim

Answer (score 0):

Make a custom event for your two different purposes.

```
dispatchEvent(new Event("SwankleChange"));
```

Though for debugging and readability purposes you'll want to use a static constant instead of plain text most likely.

```
public static const SWANKLE_CHANGE:String = "SwankleChange"; //in your class that contains your swankle methods
```

Then you can do this:

```
dispatchEvent(new Event(SWANKLE_CHANGE));
```

And:

```
swankleClassInstance.addEventListener(SwankleClass.SWANKLE_CHANGE, doSomething); //SwankleClass is whatever the class name is that contains the code you posted
```

Comment: Nice! I'll try this and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Hi I tried this, and it is not working. First I tried it with just the string in the model class: dispatchEvent (new Event ("GAP_CHANGE")); Then I added the listener to MainView. I tried _model.addEventListener("GAP_CHANGE", GapChangeHandler); and also this.addEventListener... and just regular addEventListener. The change handler is never triggered for any of them.

Comment: I also tried the way with the constant. In the model class I say:   public static const GAP_CHANGE:String = "GAP_CHANGE" and then in the setter:  dispatchEvent (new Event (GAP_CHANGE));  The  in MainView I tried addEventListener(_model.GAP_CHANGE, GapChangeHandler); and get this error:  Property GAP_CHANGE not found on com...Model
I also tried this.addEventListener and _model.addEventListener

Comment: Alright! I was able to get the string version working, but when I try to do the public constant it gives me an error in then MainView class on the line where the listener is added. It is saying "GAP_CHANGE is not a property of the class Model"

Comment: Can you update your question to show the code your using.  Include how you instantiate the class that your dispatching the event in and where you're adding the event listener.

Comment: Most likely your trying to access the static const on the instance of the class, not the class itself. Static vars are accessed on the Class itself.